# How to query results by month wise in Firestore Timestamp field for android?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview, google-cloud-firestore, timestamp-with-timezone

I want to display the data by monthwise in recyclerview,
I have a field in firestore db as "delivery_Date"= Timestamp(ServerTimestamp)

I have tried to filter by month wise but it displays empty recyclerview

This is my code in Kotlin

```
val docRef = db.collection("All Booking ID")
                .whereEqualTo("driverId", auth.currentUser?.uid)
                .whereEqualTo("status","Completed")
                    .whereGreaterThanOrEqualTo("delivery_Date","2021-02")
                    .whereLessThan("delivery_Date","2021-03")
                .orderBy("delivery_Date")


            val options : FirestoreRecyclerOptions<Service> = FirestoreRecyclerOptions.Builder<Service>()
                .setQuery(docRef, Service::class.java)
                .build()


            adapterService = AdapterService(applicationContext, options, this@BarChartCompletedList)
            adapterService?.notifyDataSetChanged()
            recyclerViewServices.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(applicationContext)

            recyclerViewServices.adapter = adapterService
            recyclerViewServices.setHasFixedSize(true)

            adapterService?.startListening()
```

Anybody help me to sort out the results in timestamp field ...
Thank You !

Comment: Your `delivery_Date` property holds a String value and **not** a Date, as needed in order to be able to use `whereGreaterThanOrEqualTo` and `whereLessThan`. Please check the duplicate to see how you can solve this.

Comment: I know it is in String and not works but how can i put that String as Timestamp ?

Comment: Please see the duplicate. You should use Timestamp object for that.